# Can't use variable in parentheses only direct input to convert dms to dd

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function, variables

I know this could be considered a duplicate question, but in all fairness I have been researching this for the last week trying everyone's methods but all ending the same way.

Basically they all work then you input the value directly, but when you try to reference a variable it gives an "NAN" response.

For example if I wanted to call the function "LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal(myvar);" it would return "NaN".

**Updated with answer, Snippet is below.**

```js
 // set `LongCombined` as array ,
  // to preserve individual item `type` ; e.g.; `Number` , `String`
  var LongCombined = [81, 36.96, 0, 'W'];

  // set `LocationFormatter` as `Object`
  var LocationFormatter = {};

  LocationFormatter.NORTH = 'N';
  LocationFormatter.SOUTH = 'S';
  LocationFormatter.EAST = 'E';
  LocationFormatter.WEST = 'W';

  LocationFormatter.roundToDecimal = function (inputNum, numPoints) {
      var multiplier = Math.pow(10, numPoints);
      return Math.round(inputNum * multiplier) / multiplier;
  };

  LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal = function (degrees, minutes, seconds, hemisphere) {
      var ddVal = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600;
      ddVal = (hemisphere == LocationFormatter.SOUTH || hemisphere == LocationFormatter.WEST) ? ddVal * -1 : ddVal;
      return LocationFormatter.roundToDecimal(ddVal, 5);
  };
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal(81, 36.96, 0, 'W');

  // call `LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal` utilizing `.apply()`,
  // set `LocationFormatter` as `this` , pass `LongCombined` as argument to `LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal`
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal.apply(LocationFormatter, LongCombined);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This one is using a varible</p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p>This is using direct input</p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
    
</script>
```

Comment: try convertDMStoDD(parseInt(myvar))

Comment: Where is `convertDMStoDD` defined ?

Comment: Still gave a NaN response. I added a fiddle link if you want to check it out.

Comment: It's being used as an example. The real code is in the snippet and fiddle. I'll change it to clear any confusion.

Comment: @EricSGriffin See post.

Comment: A string is not arguments array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // set `LongCombined` as array ,
  // to preserve individual item `type` ; e.g.; `Number` , `String`
  var LongCombined = [81, 36.96, 0, 'W'];

  // set `LocationFormatter` as `Object`
  var LocationFormatter = {};

  LocationFormatter.NORTH = 'N';
  LocationFormatter.SOUTH = 'S';
  LocationFormatter.EAST = 'E';
  LocationFormatter.WEST = 'W';

  LocationFormatter.roundToDecimal = function (inputNum, numPoints) {
      var multiplier = Math.pow(10, numPoints);
      return Math.round(inputNum * multiplier) / multiplier;
  };

  LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal = function (degrees, minutes, seconds, hemisphere) {
      var ddVal = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600;
      ddVal = (hemisphere == LocationFormatter.SOUTH || hemisphere == LocationFormatter.WEST) ? ddVal * -1 : ddVal;
      return LocationFormatter.roundToDecimal(ddVal, 5);
  };
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal(81, 36.96, 0, 'W');

  // call `LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal` utilizing `.apply()`,
  // set `LocationFormatter` as `this` , pass `LongCombined` as argument to `LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal`
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = LocationFormatter.DMSToDecimal.apply(LocationFormatter, LongCombined);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3h7z1kv7/2/